# CGAfflineTransform UIView and CoreGraphics conflict

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm using both UIView and CoreGraphics animations in my app but when I compile, the following line gives me errors:

CGAffineTransform *baseDockTransform = (CGAfflineTransform *)[[[%c(SBIconController) sharedInstance] dock] transform];

Here is the error log:

Tweak.xm:156: warning: multiple methods named ‘-transform’ found
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:156: warning: using ‘-(CGAffineTransform)transform’
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:153: warning: also found ‘-(CATransform3D)transform’
Tweak.xm:156: error: no matching function for call to ‘UIView::UIView(CGAffineTransform)’

The compiler doesn't know which method to use. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You don't work with pointers to CGAffineTransform structs. Get rid of the asterisk

Comment: @Paul.s Okay but now I get this error. http://pastie.org/3542600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're casting everything properly.
[object dock] may return an object from which you can call transform, but unless you cast it properly the compiler will complain.

Try:

```
Instance *sbInstance = [%c(SBIconController) sharedInstance];
UIView *transformedView = [sbInstance dock]; // assuming that dock returns an instance of UIView
CGAffineTransform backDockTransform = transformView.transform;
```

There won't be much overhead in doing things this way and it's easier to read what's going on.